# Dual transient voltage supressors

Tags: voltage, transient

I've been trying to reverse engineering a monitoring system and there's a component that I can't understand. [image: TISP2125F3 Device symbol]

What does these Z symbols represent?

Answer (score 0):

They are similar to symbols used for MOV's.

The device is clearly a common-mode and differential mode surge arrestor.

Is there a part number and can you get a data sheet?

Can you get a device and physically inspect it?